A reference for the definition of a minimal polynomial when ring is noncommutative
Let $R$ be a non-commutative ring and consider $R$ as a subring of $M_n (R)$ the ring of $n\times n$ matrices with entries in $R$. Let $A\in M_n (R)$. I was wondeing if someone could give a reference for the formal definition of the minimal polynomial of $A$ and  a theorem for its existence. Thank you very much in advance.

Did you encounter this notion in a text? Could you link it, please?

@Amateur_Algebraist Yes. Sure. In this paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0024379522000507
